# How to find $\varepsilon$ and $d$ that give me an upper bound

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $x_n$ be a sequence of complex numbers and $L$ a positive real number such that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there is $N\in \mathbb N^+$ for which
$$|x_n| < L + \varepsilon, \qquad n \geq N$$
And let $z$ be a complex number with $|z| < \frac{1}L$. I'm trying to show that for sufficiently large $N$,
$$|x_n||z| < 1$$
Intuitively, since $x_n$ can always be a tiny bit bigger than $L$, I need $|z|$ to be a tiny bit smaller than $\frac{1}L$. Now I can use the bound $|z| < \frac{1}L - d$ for any $0 < d < \frac{1}L - |z|$, so I need to show that for some such $d$ and some $\varepsilon > 0$,
$$\left(L+ \varepsilon\right)\left(\frac{1}{L} - d\right) < 1$$
How can I find these $\varepsilon, d$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $z$ is some fixed complex number, hence $d$ is some fixed distance, where $|z|=\frac{1}L-d$, and $0<d<\frac{1}L$. Next, for all $n>N$, you have

$$|z||x_n|<\left(\frac{1}L-d\right)(L+\epsilon)=1-d\cdot L+\left(\frac{1}L-d\right)\epsilon$$

Note that $0<1-d\cdot L<1$, and $\left(\frac{1}L-d\right)>0$, define $\delta=1-d\cdot L$, hence $0<\delta<1$, we get

$$|z||x_n|<\delta+\frac{\delta}L\epsilon$$

In particular, you can set $\epsilon=\frac{1-\delta}{2}\cdot \frac{L}\delta>0$, then you can find $N_1$, such that

$$|x_n|<L+\epsilon,~~~\forall n>N_1$$

So you get

$$|z||x_n|<\delta+\frac{\delta}L\epsilon=\frac{1+\delta}2=1-\frac{dL}2<1$$